# Best way to handle multiple errors (Exceptions) with single "response" exceptions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception

Let say we have a typical web application:

[image]

Often happens that there are many different exceptions that come from service layer and need to be handled separately.

Is there a good way or a pattern that consolidates all exceptions into less or even single exception and still being able to handle them separately?

Answer (score 0):

The one approach I do is to throw only `ServiceException` on service layer. Inside the service call, I catch all non-service exceptions and rethrow it be encapsulating it with a `ServiceException`. That way, it makes my service API neater and simpler to handle. Unchecked exceptions are not caught in my services (as most of the enterprise containers handles transactions for unchecked exceptions differently, based on the lifecycle of the service it provides).

I hope this helps.

Comment: How do you handle different exceptions when you catch ServiceException? For example for one exception you show only an error and for another you continue silently?

Comment: I categorize each exceptions. E.g., `BusinessException` is an unchecked base exception that is thrown by the service when there is an issue found in the business. Example `UserNotFoundException` is a `BusinessException` so when a user is not found a `UserNotFoundException` is thrown. A checked `ServiceException` is a checked exception when a checked exception is thrown in the service (e.g., `FileNotFoundException`).

Comment: Well... that did not answer my question at all.

Comment: Then explain what you want to achieve.